# How to find the common values in key value pairs and put it as value in all pairs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key-value

How can I get the intersection of values in key value pairs?

I have  pairs:

> `(p, Set(n))`

in which I used `reduceByKey` and finally got:

> `(p1, Set(n1, n2)) (p2, Set(n1, n2, n3))  (p3, Set(n2, n3))`

What I want is to find n that exist in all of the pairs and put them as value. For the above data, the result would by

> `(p1, Set(n2)) (p2, Set(n2)), (p3, Set(n2))`

As long as I searched, there is no `reduceByValue` in spark. The only function that seemed closer to what i want was `reduce()` but it didn't work as the result was only one key value pair `((p3, Set(n2)))`.

Is there any way to solve it? Or should i think something else from the start?

Code:

```
val rRdd = inputFile.map(x => (x._1, Set(x._2)).reduceByKey(_++_)

val wrongRdd  = rRdd.reduce{(x, y) => (x._1, x._2.intersect(y._2))}
```

I can see why `wrongRdd` is not correct, I just put it to show how `(p3, Set(n2))`  resulted from.

Comment: After reducing you will have the value you want to put in every pair, if any. Now you need to do another pass with `map` to replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `reduce` the sets to their intersection (say, `s`), then replace `(k, v)` with `(k, s)`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("p1", Set("n1", "n2")),
  ("p2", Set("n1", "n2", "n3")),
  ("p3", Set("n2", "n3"))
))

val s = rdd.map(_._2).reduce(_ intersect _)
// s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(n2)

rdd.map{ case (k, v) => (k, s) }.collect
// res1: Array[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[String])] = Array(
//   (p1,Set(n2)), (p2,Set(n2)), (p3,Set(n2))
// )
```